# How to get the webcontent of an AssetEntry with liferay?

Tags: java, liferay

I get asset entries like this:

```
List<AssetEntry> emt = AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.getEntries(q);
```

Asset entries have many methods like `assetEntry.getTitle()` - but not to get the source(input answer of webcontent). It works in the journal liferay taglib like this:
`<liferay-ui:journal-article articleId="74550" groupId="10164" ></liferay-ui:journal-article>`

How can I get the content of the web content using AssetEntry?

Answer (score 2):

The assetEntry allows you to retrieve the web content by combining the getClassName(), which is "com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle", and the getClassPK(), that gives you the id of the web content for the assetEntry.

Having this information you can call the following:

```
JournalArticle wc = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticle(assetEntry.getClassPK());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AssetEntry assetEntry = ...;

JournalArticle article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getLatestArticle(assetEntry.getPrimaryKey());
String xmlString = article.getContent(); //whole xml content with all translations
//or
String xmlString = article.getContentByLocale(languageId); //languageId is some like 'en', 'es' ...
```

Comment: This always just throws an error like "No JournalArticle exists with the primary key 722473". Can an AssetEntry exist without a JournalArticle?

Comment: Yes @Nenotlep. An AssetEntry doesn't need to be a JournalArticle per se. Quoting from the Liferay forums: "An asset can be anything, a blog post, a journal article, a poll question/answer, ...

AssetEntry is the entity representing a specific asset."

Answer (score 1):

You can access the content form the xmlString mention above like this

```
JournalContentUtil.getDisplay(journalArticle.getGroupId(), journalArticle.getArticleId(),
            null, null, locale.toString(), xmlRequest);
```

where the xmlRequest can be generated form request and response like this

```
String xmlRequest = PortletRequestUtil.toXML(request,response);
```

and the JournalArticle can be obtained like Mark mentioned above like this

```
 JournalArticle article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getLatestArticle(assetEntry.getPrimaryKey());
```

This works fine for Liferay 6.1.1 and should work in the older versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JournalArticleResource journalArticleResourceObj = JournalArticleResourceLocalServiceUtil.getJournalArticleResource(ae.getClassPK()); 
 JournalArticle journalArticleObj = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticle(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(),journalArticleResourceObj.getArticleId());
```

journalArticleObj has all required data.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried below code, but this is the code working in default display(abstract) of asset publisher.

AssetRenderer assetRenderer = (AssetRenderer)request.getAttribute("view.jsp-assetRenderer");
String summary = assetRenderer.getSummary(locale);

You can check code in the file: /liferay/liferay620/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/html/portlet/asset_publisher/display